# ipython debugger is flooded with Qt errors after pylab import

Tags: python, ipython, ipdb

**I can't use the debugger in ipython after importing anything pyqt related.**

If I don't import anything and debug an error post-mortem like

```
$ ipython3

In [1]: abc
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-03cfd743661f> in <module>
----> 1 abc

NameError: name 'abc' is not defined

In [2]: %debug
> <ipython-input-1-03cfd743661f>(1)<module>()
----> 1 abc

ipdb>
```

all is well, but if I start ipython3 with the pyqt5 backend I get

```
$ ipython3 --pylab=qt5

In [1]: abc
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-03cfd743661f> in <module>
----> 1 abc

NameError: name 'abc' is not defined

In [2]: %debug
> <ipython-input-1-03cfd743661f>(1)<module>()
----> 1 abc

ipdb> QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QApplication(0x2105860), parent's thread is QThread(0x1ccc6c0), current thread is QThread(0x7fe7940021f0)
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QApplication(0x2105860), parent's thread is QThread(0x1ccc6c0), current thread is QThread(0x7fe7940021f0)
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QApplication(0x2105860), parent's thread is QThread(0x1ccc6c0), current thread is QThread(0x7fe7940021f0)
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
[...]
```

I am not developing with qt, I only use it as the backend for matplotlib. I know that this question is very vague, but I don't know where to look for a solution.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04, Python 3.6.9, ipython 7.14.0, pyqt5 5.14.2.

Comment: This is not a Qt bug but an ipython bug

Comment: Any idea where to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is resolved with upgrading the pip package "prompt_toolkit" via

```
$ pip3 install --upgrade prompt_toolkit  # optionally --user
```

For me it went from version 2.0.10 to 3.0.5.

Comment: As of mid-August 2020, prompt_toolkit is now at 3.0.6. That did NOT work for me, but 3.0.5, as at the time of this post, resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

As far as your problem is concerned, I have made a couple of searches around that specific *error* and I have found that this error entirely belongs to `ipyhton` as the same kind of issues have been already available on [ipython official github-issues](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues) as given here:

- [ipython-issue #8086](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/8086)

I was also struck with the same problem but I have *alternatives*. I have performed a couple of tests to debug using `ipython`. Here are some combinations that can resolve your problem.

```
 - Either by using 
 ~$ ipython --pylab=qt5

 - Or by using 
 ~$ ipython3 --pylab=qt4
```

---

**Update**

---

You can use either of these methods to get your work done. But make sure, you have follow all of the given steps one by one.

**Method.1**

- Using `ipython --pylab=qt5`

For this, open your terminal and run the following commands:

```
~$ sudo killall apt apt-get
~$ sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock && sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock && sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock* && sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt update
```

After that, you have to install these things as follows:

```
~$ sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module 
~$ sudo apt-get install python-pip
~$ pip install ipython
~$ sudo apt-get install python-pyqt5
~$ pip install pyside2 && pip install matplotlib
```

After installing all of these modules, just run this command: `ipython --pylab=qt5`, you will see with few `exceptions`, `ipython` process will be instantiated.

---

**Method.2**

- Using `ipython3 --pylab=qt4`

For this, open your terminal and run the following commands:

```
~$ sudo killall apt apt-get
~$ sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock && sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock && sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock* && sudo dpkg --configure -a && sudo apt update
```

After that, you have to install these things as follows:

```
~$ sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module 
~$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
~$ pip3 install ipython3
~$ sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt4
~$ pip3 install pyside2 && pip3 install matplotlib
```

After installing all of these modules, just run this command: `ipython3 --pylab=qt4`, you will see `ipython` process will be instantiated.

---

Now, you can use either of the above-given techniques *to use it as the backend* for `matplotlib`. Here is the output of one of the tests from the above techniques:

- using `ipython3 --pylab=qt4`

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer and looking into this! Sadly I have the same problem with qt4. Concerning `ipython`, maybe it works for you because it starts an Python 2 shell instead of Python 3? This is unfortunately not an option for me.

Comment: Then you should update your `Sudo` and re-install this stuff. I hope that would work. I have to update everything before performing the tests. I Hope, my efforts would be appreciated. Let me know, how can I further help you?

Comment: Thank you, but that also does not fix the problem.

Comment: @clemisch Can we arrange a *Zoom* Chat? Let me jump into your machine to resolve your issue.

Comment: I appreciate the offer, but no. If this problem would be solved by updating all packages I would not have posted a SO question.

Comment: This issue is due to `ipython` itself. You don't have to worry about that. But these alternatives are working fine, as I have tested same techniques on *two other machines* of my colleagues using the same specs you have given on `github`.

Comment: What OS are you running? I don't have installation candidates for neither `python3-pyqt4` in apt nor `pyqt4` in pip for Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: I am using  `Ubuntu 18.04` as my OS. Run these two commands and give me the output of your python `sys_version`. 1. `python -c "import IPython; print(IPython.sys_info())"`, 2. `python3 -c "import IPython; print(IPython.sys_info())"`.

Comment: @clemisch I have updated my answer. You can revisit and let me know if you still get some errors.